# Facebook ios static library:build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib not found

Tags: ios, facebook

I am following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) tutorial to integrate Facebook in my iOS app.

The tutorial asks to build a static library - if iOS app uses Arc - using the below sh file found in scripts folder

% ~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh

But I cannot find this file anywhere..

even here in GitHub for facebook sdk..
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/scripts

Somebody please help me where to find this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/msealand/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/51971551dfd69e02ddcd78fc174bc1a84cd8beb4/scripts

It's there! If my answer's helpful, please 'tick' mark my reply and give a +1 !

Thanks
Jean